# Duplicated POST method , why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm having problems when submitting a form, it's making a duplicate post method, and I don't know why because i have prevent Default in my js. Any iluminatti in the room?

**My JS**

```
<% if @photo.user = current_user %>
 <script> $("#tp_tag_save").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/users/<%= current_user.id %>/photos/<%= @photo.id %>/tags", {
      "tag[name]" : $("#tag_name").val(),
      "tag[location]" : $("#tag_location").val(),
      "tag[price]" : $("#tag_price").val(),
      "tag[coordinate_x]" : $("#tag_coordinate_x").val(),
      "tag[coordinate_y]" : $("#tag_coordinate_y").val()
    }).done(function (data) {
      drawTag($("#tag_name").val(), $("#tag_price").val(), $("#tag_location").val(), $("#tag_coordinate_x").val(), $("#tag_coordinate_y").val()),
      reDrawList();
    });
    modal("#tag_modal", "hide", 200);
  });
</script>
<% end %>
```

**My Form**

```
<div class="large-5 center semi_padding_top columns large-centered ">
    <h1> <i class="icon-photo"></i>Subir un spot</h1>
    <h6 class="lightgrey thin">Los spots son rincones de tu casa, oficina o negocio de los que estés orgulloso de cómo están decorados. </h6>
    <%= simple_form_for [current_user, @photo] , html_input: "data-abide" do |f| %>
        <div class="new_spot_form deco-form semi_padding_top">
            <%= f.input :title , label: "Ponle un título a tu spot", html_input: "required", class: "input" %>
            <%= f.input :description, label: "¿Qué te gusta de este spot?" , class: "textarea" %>
            <%= f.input :photo, label: "Ahora sube tu foto", input_html: { id: 'fileElem'} %>
            <button id="fileSelect" class="semi_margin_bottom" type="button"><i class="valign-m quarter_padding_right icon-magnifier"></i>Seleccionar spot</button>
            <%= f.label "Selecciona el estilo de tu spot" %>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name%>
            <%= f.label "Selecciona la zona de tu spot" %>
            <%= f.collection_select :zone_id, Zone.all, :id, :name %>
            <%= f.input :terms , label: "Tengo los derechos de esta foto" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Subir Spot", input_html: {class: 'icon-magnifier button'} %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: @Pete No, no errors in console...it's really weird...

Comment: The most common reason is that the event is bound twice. `$("#tp_tag_save").on('click', function(event) {})` specifically. 

If that line of code runs twice, for any reason, cilcking the DOM element with that ID will fire twice. 

Make sure you only bind the event once

Comment: @Patrick I know, but the problem is I can't see where I'm binding that twice!

Comment: @Patrick found it! I had a switch method in another js with that #id, I just searched in sublime all of my files.

Comment: You can add a `console.log("clicked!")` in the click callback to see how many times "clicked" appear in the console

Comment: There ya go! Also note that with you understanding what the problem is(you understood the event was bound twice), There was no way of us helping with the code you posted :P As actually the ID being set on the vent isn't even shown in the code

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I didn't realize the problem was coming from another javascript. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

how do you call your js code?
I see one mistake in it

```
<% if @photo.user = current_user %>
```

If you use this code in loop it will be called twice.

In that case rewrite

```
<% if @photo.user == current_user %>
```

Comment: I don't know if it was this or the other thing that duplicated the stuff!